# Email attachment not received in EmailService handler

Tags: attachment, apex-email-service

I have an issue with processing inbound emails sent from MS Outlook. To put it simple no attachments are received in the class (nor text nor binary). Email definitely has attachments since i cc-ed the email to my gmail account.

If the email with attachment is sent from the gmail account everything works well.

Any thoughts or experiences?

the code:

```
global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope env) 
    {
        System.debug(email);//no attachments all attachment binary and text are null
....}
```

I think this source could be more important:

Gmail source:

```
Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8; name="Karol_csv_short.csv"  
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Karol_csv_short.csv"  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
X-Attachment-Id: f_hytz9oxg0
```

Outlook source

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name="Karol_csv_short.csv"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Karol_csv_short.csv"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
X-Attachment-Id: 1cad76b11d272e29_0.1
```

So the issue could be that the *application/vnd.ms-excel* content type is not understood by salesforce?

Thanks

Comment: same issue as the one described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630493/salesforce-email-services-dosent-work-with-outlook-or-lotus-notes merge suggestion?

Comment: No merge since the question is on stack overflow

Comment: If you have a custom inbound email service, I recommend you post the code for it. Otherwise, we're all simply making guesses.

Comment: Hi it's not about the code but ok  'global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail email,
                Messaging.InboundEnvelope env) 
 {
  System.debug(email);//no attachments all attachment binary and text are null
....}'

Comment: Please edit your post to include your code rather than asking us to read it in comments. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @crmprogdev, but i must state that the description itself was enough

Comment: @crmprogdev why you removed your answer? and downvoted the question?

Comment: I asked you to post your code, you now tell me there were 200 lines in your code and that my answer did not apply. I have wasted my time because you didn't provide more code when it was requested and my answer serves no real purpose.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16423/discussion-between-zokito-and-crmprogdev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just managed to do a workaround this issue...

I managed to found a way for inbound service to receive the attachments sent from MS Outlook. It seems that SFDC email service under the hood has a limited scope of *Content-Type:* headers it handles. If the *.csv* file is attached from Outlook it adds the header value not understood by salesforce *Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel* the attachment is then dropped by SFDC and it never reaches **Messaging.InboundEmailHandler** implementation.

First I'd like to stress out that this behavior presented by SFDC is invalid and that they should treat all unknown *Content-Type:* values as *application/octet-stream* and push them to **InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment[] binaryAttachments** property.

Then i tried to change the extension of the file to none, attach it in Outlook and see what will happen. Nothing did - again SFDC dropped the attachment which brings me to conclude that SF does not handle *application/octet-stream* at all.

Take three - I changed the extension of the file to plain old *.txt* and did the attach/send drill again and it worked. *Content-Type:* was set to *text/plain; charset=UTF-8;* by Outlook and SFDC understood it properly adding the file to the **InboundEmail.TextAttachment[] textAttachments** property.

So to highlight the resolution if somebody finds him/her self in this quite weird situation:

**Just change the extension of the file to .txt if it is a .csv file you're trying to push to salesforce from Outlook**